# Read into a bytearray at an offset?

Tags: python, io, python-3.x, buffer

How can I use the [`readinto()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.readinto) method call to an offset inside a [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#bytearray), in the same way that [`struct.unpack_from`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from) works?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a [`memoryview`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) to do the job. For example:

```
dest = bytearray(10) # all zero bytes
v = memoryview(dest)
ioObject.readinto(v[3:])
print(repr(dest))
```

Assuming that `iObject.readinto(...)` reads the bytes 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 then this code prints:

```
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x00\x00')
```

You can also use the `memoryview` object with `struct.unpack_from` and `struct.pack_into`. For example:

```
dest = bytearray(10) # all zero bytes
v = memoryview(dest)
struct.pack_into("2c", v[3:5], 0, b'\x07', b'\x08')
print(repr(dest))
```

This code prints

```
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x07\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

Comment: My intention is to read directly into the bytearray at an offset, and avoid all the intermediate copying.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an example using the `memoryview` class, which I think does what you want.

Comment: This memoryview form seems to accomplish what I wanted. If I did a similar thing with struct.unpack_into, and used a memoryview instead of an offset, would it be the same? If this is the case, please remove the rest of your answer to focus on this.

Comment: Thanks, I was checking whether I need to add this as an answer